# How to store Subform selection data to a Listbox?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I need to create a form that filters a subform by keyword search, then allow users to select records and display these selections in a list box.

I have a text box `txtKeywords` that filters a subform `sfrmParts` by `txtKeyword` search. `sfrmParts` contains a list of information such as part number, description and cost. This `sfrmParts` is pulling data from a larger table of parts and information `tblParts`.

How can I have the user select a record from `sfrmParts` then have this record info displayed in a ListBox? In essence, I would like the user to be able to search and select a number of different parts to add and build a kit. The ListBox should display all the records the user has chosen.Once a kit is built then the user can save this combination of parts.

I'm fairly new to Access, so I don't know if this is the right approach. Suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: I don't know if this is right approach either. What do you intend to do with the listbox items? Perhaps you should be saving selected items to a table instead. Regardless, will need VBA. As opposed to a form bound to destination table and selecting parts from a combobox list to create records - normal old-fashioned data entry.

Comment: I'm looking to have a subform display a table of parts (only three columns of information out of many). I would like to have the user search through the subform (or whatever is recommended) to filter the table and make a selection. This selection can then be added to another display on the same form to show which parts have been selected. From here I need to save these selections somewhere else.

Comment: My previous comment still applies. What you described will be complicated to accomplish whereas the alternative I described is not. Your question does not have any code to analyze and is really too broad for SO. When you have code with specific issue, post question.

Comment: So you are suggesting that I approach this by saving the SubForm records to another table? Just need the right direction to keep working on this, thank you! :)

Comment: I suggest you do normal data entry with form bound to destination table and a combobox to select each part one at a time to create records. Anything else will require code.

Comment: I will work on this, thanks again